# Java xml binding with wrong xmlns attribute name

Tags: java, jaxb

When I use the annotation:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="RootElement", namespace="namespace")
class RootElement {
```

to create xml file from java, it creates the root element as:

```
<ns2:RootElement xmlns:ns2="namespace">
```

but I wanted to create without the "ns2", like:

```
<RootElement xmlns="namespace">
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Reletad link (example I used to create the xml):
http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.xml.bind.annotation/XmlRootElementname.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JAXB doesn't use `xmlns = "namespace"` in your case because `xmlns = "namespace"` also specifies namespace for the child elements, then your `first` and `last` elements are in default namespace (because `@XmlRootElement` doesn't specify namespace for the child elements). So, you need to set namespace for `first` and `last` using `@XmlElement`:

```
  @XmlElement(namespace = "namespace")
  public String getFirst() {
    return first;
  }

  ...

  @XmlElement(namespace = "namespace")
  public String getLast() {
    return last;
  }
```

You can also avoid the need to write namespace for every element by using package-level annotation in `package-info.java`:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    namespace = "namespace",
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package foo;
```

Comment: is there any way i can force jaxb to use xmlns="" if my child elements are from the same namespace ? 
check my question..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889133/xml-marshalling-i-want-namespace-attributes-and-not-prefixes